# extends and implements in one class in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, extends, implements

Can I do this in TypeScript?

```ts
export interface IMyInterface {
  doSomething(): void;
}

export class MyBaseClass {
  myBaseClassHasProperty: string;

  constructor(){
    this.myBaseClassHasProperty = 'some value';
  }
  myBaseClassHasMethods(): void {
    console.log(this.myBaseClassHasProperty);
  }
}

export class MyClass extends MyBaseClass implements IMyInterface {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  doSomething(): void {
    this.myBaseClassHasMethods();
  }
}
```

In runtime it throws:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: MyBaseClass is not defined

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> in runtime i get this `Uncaught ReferenceError: MyBaseClass is not defined`

Yes you can do that. The code you posted will work fine.

However I suspect in your *actual code* you have it split across multiple files and `MyBaseClass` is *not executed* before the code for `MyClass`.

Fix JavaScript ordering or use external modules to have the ordering determined by the module loader.

Comment: yes, i'm was using tsconfig.json to compile to only one app.js file and the tsc was creating a MyBaseClass.js file. 
But still not working, the tsc is not creating the __extends code on js file, I will gonna try more later. - tsc --version 1.4.1.0 on Mac OS X 10.8